# Amazon Scraper Script works on XAMPP Windows but not PHP5 Cli on Linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape Amazon ASIN codes using the below code:

```
<?php

class Scraper {

const BASE_URL = "http://www.amazon.com";
private $categoryFile = "";
private $outputFile = "";
private $catArray;
private $currentPage = NULL;
private $asin = array();
private $categoriesMatched = 0;
private $categoryProducts = array();
private $pagesMatched = 0;
private $totalPagesMatched = 0;
private $productsMatched = 0;

public function __construct($categoryFile, $outputFile) {

    $this->categoryFile = $categoryFile;
    $this->outputFile = $outputFile;

}

public function run() {

    $this->readCategories($this->categoryFile);
    $this->setupASINArray($this->asin);

    $x = 1;

    foreach ($this->catArray as $cat) {

        $this->categoryProducts["$x"] = 0;

        if ($this->currentPage == NULL) {

            $this->currentPage = $cat;
            $this->scrapeASIN($this->currentPage, $x);
            $this->pagesMatched++;

        }           

        if ($this->getNextPageLink($this->currentPage)) {

            do {

                // next page found
                $this->pagesMatched++;
                $this->scrapeASIN($this->currentPage, $x);

            } while ($this->getNextPageLink($this->currentPage));

        }

        echo "Category complete: $this->pagesMatched Pages" . "\n";
        $this->totalPagesMatched += $this->pagesMatched;
        $this->pagesMatched = 0;
        $this->writeASIN($this->outputFile, $x);
        $x++;
        $this->currentPage = NULL;
        $this->categoriesMatched++;



    }

    $this->returnStats();


}

private function readCategories($categoryFile) {

    $catArray = file($categoryFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    $this->catArray = $catArray;

}

private function setupASINArray($asinArray) {

    $x = 0;

    foreach ($this->catArray as $cat) {

        $asinArray["$x"][0] = "$cat";
        $x++;

    }

    $this->asin = $asinArray;

}

private function getNextPageLink($currentPage) {

    $document = new DOMDocument();

    $html = file_get_contents($currentPage);

    @$document->loadHTML($html);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

    $element = $xpath->query("//a[@id='pagnNextLink']/@href");

    if ($element->length != 0) {

        $this->currentPage = self::BASE_URL . $element->item(0)->value;
        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }


}

private function scrapeASIN($currentPage, $catNo) {

    $html = file_get_contents($currentPage);

    $regex = '~(?:www\.)?ama?zo?n\.(?:com|ca|co\.uk|co\.jp|de|fr)/(?:exec/obidos/ASIN/|o/|gp/product/|(?:(?:[^"\'/]*)/)?dp/|)(B[A-Z0-9]{9})(?:(?:/|\?|\#)(?:[^"\'\s]*))?~isx';

    preg_match_all($regex, $html, $asin);

    foreach ($asin[1] as $match) {

        $this->asin[$catNo-1][] = $match;

    }   


}

private function writeASIN($outputFile, $catNo) {

    $fh = fopen($outputFile, "a+");

    $this->fixDupes($catNo);
    $this->productsMatched += (count($this->asin[$catNo-1]) - 1);
    $this->categoryProducts["$catNo"] = (count($this->asin[$catNo-1]) - 1);

    flock($fh, LOCK_EX);

    $x = 0;

    foreach ($this->asin[$catNo-1] as $asin) {

        fwrite($fh, "$asin" . "\n");

        $x++;

    }



    flock($fh, LOCK_UN);

    fclose($fh);

    $x -= 1;

    echo "$x ASIN codes written to file" . "\n";

}

private function fixDupes($catNo) {

    $this->asin[$catNo-1] = array_unique($this->asin[$catNo-1], SORT_STRING);

}

public function returnStats() {

    echo "Categories matched: " . $this->categoriesMatched . "\n";
    echo "Pages parsed: " . $this->totalPagesMatched . "\n";
    echo "Products parsed: " . $this->productsMatched . "\n";
    echo "Category breakdown:" . "\n";

    $x = 1;

    foreach ($this->categoryProducts as $catProds) {

        echo "Category $x had $catProds products" . "\n";
        $x++;

    }

}

}

$scraper = new Scraper($argv[1], $argv[2]);
$scraper->run();

?>
```

But it works fine on XAMPP on Windows but not on Linux. Any ideas as to why this may be? Sometimes it scrapes 0 ASIN's to file, sometimes it only scrapes 1 page in a category of 400+ pages. But the output/functionality is totally fine in Windows/XAMPP.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers
- Bryce

Comment: funny thing :-) so what is your `$argv[1], $argv[2]` values?? I guess that is some file path?? ex `c:\amazonscrapperfiles\categories.csv` ?? does this file/path exists under linux?

Comment: Yeah it's an input new line delimited text file and output text file for storing the asins in a new line delimited format

Comment: no it is not a file, it a string with path to the file~ isn't it? so do you have that file path under linux filesystem?

Comment: Maybe amazon is blocking you?

Comment: @KimAlexander the file is in the same folder (containing a subcategory or category url) as the script, so it'd be executed like php Scraper.php input.txt output.txt - it always writes the url to the file, just not the ASIN's

Comment: did you try my answer??? you still not answer my question: what is the value of `$argv[1]` ?? do var_dump please, and show output!

Answer (score 0):

So try to change this way, just to avoid the error messages:

```
private function readCategories($categoryFile) {

if (file_exists($categoryFile)) {
    $catArray = file($categoryFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    $this->catArray = $catArray;
} else {
    echo "File ".$categoryFile.' not exists!';
    $this->catArray = array();
}

}
```

Comment: the file is in the same folder (containing a subcategory or category url) as the script, so it'd be executed like php Scraper.php input.txt output.txt - it always writes the url to the file, just not the ASIN's

Comment: The folder it is in, is the same folder as the script that is running - ie, when argv[1] and argv[2] are supplied, the script searches relative to it's current path for them. It's definitely not the files not being found.

Comment: so you did check with my code, and you've got negative result?

Comment: The category file is being read, as the category is being written to the output file. The only way this is possible, is that the category file is read by file() into the array intially. Thanks for your persistence though!